# How to link Keycloak docker image to MariaDB docker

Tags: docker, mariadb, keycloak

I have a Maria DB docker image for my application.

I've now pulled Keycloak image. It is using the default h2. But I want to use my existing maria DB image

The documentation is asking me to create network etc, but I am not sure how I do it in cloud. So looking for a configuration based solution i.e. change Keycloak image config to link to Maria DB image. I am not using docker compose, I only pulled image.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md#environment-variables

Not sure what is environment variables - are these inside keycloak image or on host machine?

start command:  docker run -p 7080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak

and I find it is highly unsecure. Is there a secure way?

**Edit**:
I opened cli from docker dashboard, and typed

> env

but do not know how can I add more env variables like

> ```
> PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
> # PostgreSQL DB settings
> DB_VENDOR: postgres
> DB_ADDR: 172.17.0.1
> DB_PORT: 5432
> DB_DATABASE: keycloak
> DB_SCHEMA: public
> DB_USER: keycloak
> DB_PWD: keycloak
> ```

(how to change PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true from false ?)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it like this. You need to define a network and add database and keycloak services to that network.

To add the env variables you have to define them under environment block.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  demo_db:
    container_name: demo-maria-db
    image: mariadb:10.5.8-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /apps/demo/db:/data/db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      demo_mesh:
        aliases:
          - demo-db

  demo_keycloak:
    container_name: demo-keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      DB_VENDOR: mariadb
      DB_ADDR: demo-db
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    depends_on:
      - demo_db
    networks:
      - demo_mesh

networks:
  demo_mesh: {}
```

Comment: I am looking for an answer that starts with "docker pull jboss/keycloak" and then change config to utilize my existing mariaDB. I can open a terminal and use commands set or env etc. But that container doesnt have vi or nano that I know. I am thinking of some steps that tell - how to get a basic editor , update env variables i.e. add new...and see if that works

Comment: try installing vim inside container 
apt-get update
apt-get install vim

Comment: I see this in the articl. Does it mean I cant update - Docker start and stop

This image supports docker start and docker stop commands, but will not detect any changes in configuration. If you would like to reconfigure Keycloak, you must create a new container.

Comment: My concern to lift the above yml or https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/master/docker-compose-examples is security. where will I save the file. and if it is some git hub or bitbucket , am I not exposing the passwords?

Comment: if you want to create admin user without adding credentials in docker-compose you can do it manually by using add-user-keycloak.sh script. This is located in /opt/jboss/keycloak in container